# More Kotlin way for a Sum of a Number

Tags: kotlin

I got a function that is working pretty well. But I'm new to Kotlin so I like to ask for a more Kotlin like way. My Algorithm is pretty standard. So my Question is: Is there a way to get the same Result just with Kotlin known Functions or something like a more Kotlin like way ?

```
fun sumOfdivider(numerToCalculate: Int) : MutableList<Int>{
  var CalculationNumer = numerToCalculate
  val numberList = ArrayList<Int>()
  var helpCounter = 1

  while (CalculationNumer > 1) {
    if (helpCounter > CalculationNumer) {
        helpCounter /= 2
        numberList.add(helpCounter)
        CalculationNumer -= helpCounter
        helpCounter = 1
    } else {
        helpCounter *= 2
    }
  }

  return numberList
}
```

Comment: I do a change of the method name/variables

Comment: Can you please describe in words what the algorithm is supposed to do?

Comment: Can you describe in words what your method is doing? I put in some values and I can't find a pattern as to what it's supposed to do...

Comment: Sure:
I want to pass an arbitrary number.
Now I want to check which numbers exist within the given number. 
Now I had thought a "bitwise" similar approach. But I am also very open for other approaches.

Comment: Okay, after trying a few more powers of 2, and near powers of 2 I figured it out. You want powers of 2 that sum to the given number? Then wouldn't giving `21` give `[16,4,1]` as output? Your current implementation gives `[16,4]` only. Is that intended?

Comment: nah it wasn´t intended.You where right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is with higher order functions:

```
fun powersOf2ThatSumsTo(num: Int) =
    (0 until (32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(num)))
            .filter { num ushr it and 1 == 1 }
            .map { 1 shl it }
```

`32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(num)` is the position of the most significant 1 bit. `0 until` that number forms the range of positions that we need to check. You can also do `0 until 32`, which checks the entire 32 bits.

For each position, we check if that position has a 1 bit. We do this by checking if shifting `num` that many places to the right and its LSB ends up being a 1. If that position has a 1 bit, we keep it, otherwise we throw it away, hence the `filter`.

Then for each remaining position, we shift 1 that many places to the left. This turns the position 2 into 4, position 3 into 8, position 4 into 16, etc. This is the "place value" of the binary number.

This produces the results in ascending order, e.g. `[16, 4]` for input `20`. Your original method produces them in descending order. If you would like the same order, you can do `31 downTo 0` instead of `0 until 32`.

Comment: thats magic :D
i like that way, as well as you explained that